# Sending Linux commands over serial connection to an Android device

Tags: linux, shell, android, serial-port

I have a question about being able to send Linux commands over a serial connection to an Android device.

I have heard of PuTTY and tried to use it, but I am ultimately lost with it.

I was in the Linux shell of the Android device and could type, `reboot` and the device would reboot. The Android device has a virtual serial connection, and I have been able to connect to it using PuTTY, but I don't know where to go after that.

Also, I cannot use ADB because the phone will not fully boot, and the ADB setting is on.

Comment: *"I don't know where to go after that."*  -- Seems like you have a working serial link to the console.  The next step is you need to learn shell commands.  Try typing `help` or `busybox`.  Putty is a **terminal emulation program**; it's the program that is running on the PC side of the link so that you can use the serial port + keyboard + monitor as a "terminal" or console.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that the connection I had was for the phone modem, not to the system. There seems to be (on many qualcomm phones) a modem connection and then the adb connection for the android system.

So it ended up being a dead end.

Answer (score 0):

If you are communicating over a serial connection I think you would use AT commands rather than 'linux commands.'

[This](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1471241) post discusses something similar if my understanding is correct.

Comment: AT commands are for controlling a **phone modem** or a communications device that emulates a phone modem because it has a data (or transparent) mode and a command mode.  A simple serial link like what the OP has does not have a modem.  Hence there is no device to process any AT commands.